# Bug: Flags underlining overlaps text

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging, profile-page

Provided you've flagged something helpful, select your flag summary. This has recently become underlined due to [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220038/does-the-flagging-history-summary-need-improvement)

However on this site, due to its particular styling of underlines, the underline runs into the text

[image: flagging underlining on money]

For comparison this is what underlining looks like on Stack Overflow and other Stack sites.

[image]

Comment: Does not reproduce for me.  I see a "regular" horizontal line there, identical to your StackOverflow pic.

Comment: It's been fixed by someone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that (although I don't have any active flags):

[image: Flags]

(Of course, perhaps it was just fixed?)

Comment: It was just fixed.